# Extract complete Transaction Details of every single transaction

Tags: web3j

I am creating a Java Backend using Web3J and subscribing to `replayPastAndFutureBlocksFlowable` from block 1 to latest, and then all subsequent new blocks.

From this, I get all the transactions, which  I save it in the DB.

The problem is that, there are ERC20 transactions as well. In the tx Object, the toAddress is a smart contract address. What I want is to extract the actual from and toAddress where the token was transferred, amount, symbol, etc and then store that in my Database.

Basically, all transactions : deposits, withdrawal, of all ETH tokens, and all ERC20 tokens in database for analytics.

I am able to work with ETH transactions, which is pretty simple, but there is literally no clue how to extract the ERC20 details from the transaction Object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to extract the information that you said from **data** parameter of the ERC20 transaction. these parameters are in hex format. etherscan.io can decode it. I just found a link (https://medium.com/coinmonks/discovering-the-secrets-of-an-ethereum-transaction-64febb00935c) for extracting data from input parameters. I'm afraid to say it is in Python format, but I think Web3J has these functions too.